# Concatenating N columns of text in R

Tags: r

I have an arbitrary number of columns containing text data that have been assembled using the cbind() command, for example:

`[1,] "Text 1,1" "Text 1,2" "Text 1,n"`
`[2,] "Text 2,1" "Text 2,2" "Text 2,n"`
`[3,] "Text 3,1" "Text 3,2" "Text 3,n"`
`[n,] "Text n,1" "Text n,2" "Text n,n"`

I want to concatenate each row together, so I'm left with:

`[1,] "Text 1,1 Text 1,2 Text 1,n"`
`[n,] "Text n,1 Text n,2 Text n,n"`

Currently, I'm doing this using a for loop (where textColumns is the cbind() matrix):

`concatColumn <- c()`
`for (i in 1:ncol(textColumns)) concatColumn <- paste(concatColumn,textColumns[,i])`

Is there a simpler, more elegant way to do this in R? I've been looking around for ways to do this using the paste() command without a for loop, but haven't been able to find a solution. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's easy with a data.frame,

```
m = matrix(letters[1:12], 3, byrow=TRUE)
do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#[1] "a b c d" "e f g h" "i j k l"
```

Comment: alternatively, `apply(m, 1, paste, collapse=" ")` to work directly on a matrix.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The apply() method works beautifully. Thank you! The converting to data.frame method gave me some weird output: `[1] "c(\"t1\", \"t2\", \"t3\")" "c(\"t4\", \"t5\", \"t6\")" "c(\"t7\", \"t8\", \"t9\")"`

Answer (score 8):

Just use `paste` with its `collapse` argument:

```
R> row <- c("Text 1,1",  "Text 1,2", "Text 1,n")
R> paste(row, collapse=" ")
[1] "Text 1,1 Text 1,2 Text 1,n"
R>
```

`paste` is vectorised, so you can feed it multiple arguments at once.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the reply. However, when dealing with multiple columns that method concatenates them all together into one character vector. For example `cols <- cbind(c("1","2","3"),c("4","5","6"),c("7","8","9"))` yields one character vector of `[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"`, whereas I need three rows with `[1] "1 4 7"` `[2] "2 5 8"` etc.