# Creating a new matrix column from concatenated values

Tags: r

I have a matrix with columns containing 0s and 1s, and I want to concatenate the values in each row to create a new column in that matrix with that concatenated string.

I used

```
apply(format(matrix), 1, paste, collapse="")
```

from 
[Concatenating N columns of text in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661514/concatenating-n-columns-of-text-in-r)
to create a list of concatenated values, but am having trouble getting those values into a new column in the matrix - the second line of this code has the wrong syntax.

my current code:

```
newcolumn <- rep(0,times=nrow(matrix))
newcolumn[matrix[apply(format(matrix), 1, paste, collapse="")]]
matrix <- cbind(matrix, newcolumn)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to read a basic introduction to R (see the [tag wiki for links](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)).

At the moment, you have created a vector of `0`'s as `newcolumn`. Your second line of code is garbage (as you rightly noted) -- see point 1.

You can  cbind the results of `apply(format(matrix), 1, paste, collapse="")` to  `matrix`. There is no need for preallocating `newcolumn`.

Note that a `matrix` can only hold a single type of data (i.e. numeric or character etc), as such if you include a `character` column then the whole matrix will be coerced to character.

```
# examples
# a character matrix containing the result + matrix coerced to character
charResults <- cbind(matrix, apply(format(matrix), 1, paste, collapse="") )


# you could use a data.frame to have different data classes in the same structure

dfResults <- cbind(as.data.frame(matrix), result = apply(format(matrix), 1, paste, collapse=""))
```

Also note, it is usually good practice not to name your objects the names of `base` R functions (such as `matrix`)

Comment: Thanks so much - I am very much in need of more of a basic intro to R, admittedly, but am unfortunately rather more rushed than I'd like in doing this project.  Your charResults code was exactly what I needed - thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

`cbind(matrix, paste0(as.character(matrix[,1]), as.character(matrix[,2])))` should do the trick. The matrix must be converted to character format to accommodate '01' cases.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a Matrix A like the following;
`A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],`
`[11,12,13,14,15,16],`
`[21,22,23,24,25,26],`
`[31,32,33,34,35,36],`
`[41,42,43,44,45,46]]`

You want to concatenate 1, 2, 3 columns with the 6.last column for constructing a new matrix as the following;
`NewA =`
`[[1, 2, 3, 6],`
`[11,12,13,16],`
`[21,22,23,26],`
`[31,32,33,36],`
`[41,42,43,46]]`

I have found the simplest solution of achieving it as;

`import numpy as np`
`NewA=np.concatenate((np.transpose(A)[0:3],np.transpose(A)[5:6])).transpose()`

I wish it is helpful to you...

Comment: The asker's question is in relation to `r` but your solution provided is for the `python` language.