# Combine columns of numbers into column with new name

Tags: r, numbers, concatenation

Surprisingly, I could not find this question among those already here.  I am sorry that this is basic.

I have this:

```
A    B    C    D     E
1    3    500  200   1 
2    3    500  200   2
3    2    500  200   1
3    3    500  200   1
```

I would like to combine columns A through D into a new column called "ROW_NAMES"

```
ROW_NAMES    E
13500200     1
23500200     2
32500200     1
33500200     1
```

Comment: What programming language do you want to make it in? Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: You had "Paste" in your title...did you _really_ try yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating N columns of text in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661514/concatenating-n-columns-of-text-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might surprise you, but there is a function `paste` and a convenience version `paste0`:

```
df <- within(df, ROW_NAMES <- paste0(A, B, C , D))
df[, 6:5]
#   ROW_NAMES E
# 1  13500200 1
# 2  23500200 2
# 3  32500200 1
# 4  33500200 1
```

Or if you want to paste many columns and want less typing:

```
df$ROW_NAMES <- do.call(paste0, df[, -5])
df[, 6:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste2 in the qdap package would be one way to approach this:

```
## dat <- read.table(text="A    B    C    D     E
## 1    3    500  200   1 
## 2    3    500  200   2
## 3    2    500  200   1
## 3    3    500  200   1 ", header=TRUE)


library(qdap)
data.frame(ROW_NAMES=paste2(dat[, 1:4], sep=""), E=dat$E)

## > data.frame(ROW_NAMES=paste2(dat[, 1:4], sep=""), E=dat$E)
##   ROW_NAMES E
## 1  13500200 1
## 2  23500200 2
## 3  32500200 1
## 4  33500200 1
```