# Concatenate data.frame character columns based on column index stored as a vector in R w/ dplyr mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr

Can one concatenate data frame columns based on the column index stored as a vector, possibly using a stringr function (eg., str_c() ) or paste? And then, how can I do so to create a new variable using dplyr mutate()?

I would like to do so for an email aggregation task that will mean reading Excel worksheets containing varying name columns (e.g., just one Name column and sometimes First and Last Names), using the readxl package.

For example:
Say I wanted to concatenate all of the column names containing "color" in the starwars data frame installed with the tidyverse R package.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 colnames(starwars)
 [1] "name"       "height"     "mass"       "hair_color" "skin_color" "eye_color"  "birth_year" "gender"     "homeworld"  "species"    "films"     
 [12] "vehicles"   "starships"
```

I could capture the index of those columns with:

```
color_vec_num <- which(grepl("COLOR", toupper(colnames(starwars))))
print(color_vec_num)
[1] 4 5 6
```

What are the column names?

```
colnames(starwars)[color_vec_num]
[1] "hair_color" "skin_color" "eye_color"
```

I can link together those column names easily enough by name. Looking at the first 4 rows of starwars:

```
str_c(starwars$hair_color, starwars$skin_color, starwars$eye_color)[1:4]
[1] "blondfairblue"   NA                NA                "nonewhiteyellow"
```

However, my attempts at using the column index have failed.

*Edit per Akrun's discovery of a typo* Borrowing this [SO use of double brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618744/dplyr-how-to-reference-columns-by-column-index-rather-than-column-name-using-mu) to create (mutate) a new variable works, but this identifies columns singularly and explicitly rather than using a numeric vector to identify each column index.

```
starwars %>% mutate(newcolor = paste(.[[4]],.[[5]], .[[6]])) %>% select(name, newcolor)
# A tibble: 87 x 2
   name               newcolor                    
   <chr>              <chr>                       
 1 Luke Skywalker     blond fair blue             
 2 C-3PO              NA gold yellow              
 3 R2-D2              NA white, blue red
```

This attempt, reminiscent of a [previous SO answer for a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661514/concatenating-n-columns-of-text-in-r), obviously doesn't look right.

```
paste(starwars %>% select(color_vec_num), collapse = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
[1] "c(\"blond\", NA, NA, \"none\", \"brown\", \"brown, grey\", \"brown\", NA, \"black\", \"auburn, white\", \"blond\", \"auburn, grey\", \"brown\", \"brown\", NA, NA,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the columns with the column index (`.[color_vec_num]`) and `reduce` it to a single column/vector in `mutate` by concatenating (`str_c`)

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- starwars %>%
           mutate(newcolor = reduce(.[color_vec_num], str_c))
out %>% 
   pull(newcolor) %>% 
   head(4)
#[1] "blondfairblue"   NA                NA                "nonewhiteyellow"
```

---

Regarding the error in OP's `paste`

```
paste(.[[4]],.[[5]], [[6]]
```

the last one is missing `.` i.e. it should be

```
starwars %>%
   mutate(newcolor = paste(.[[4]],.[[5]], .[[6]]))
```

Having said that, there is a distinct advantage in using `str_c` when compared to `paste` or `unite` (from `tidyr`) with regards to missing values.  With `str_c`, any missing value in a column returns `NA` for the whole row while `paste` or `unite` converts the `NA` to character and returns something like

```
"NA gold yellow"
```

for the second element while it is `NA` for `str_c`